# Unable to display a png file with Angular and Symfony (BinaryFileResponse)

Tags: angular, symfony, png, binaryfiles

How to read a binary string with angular 4 ?

I send a png from angular 4 to symfony (it works !) and I return the png from symfony to Angular4 with BinaryFileResponse.

- I try `new Blob()` with url generate and sanitizer ( tedious and it doesn't work )
- I try `Uint8Array()` ( it does not work ) // Array is empty

On the other hand,`"Postman"` displays my png.

Comment: i think there is a option to make image inline by passing the row data as string in ui

Comment: thank you but I think I just found the solution, it was enough to simply put the route of my controller's action in source of the image and it returns the image... <img src="myApi/image"/>

Comment: That make sense